# Insert emoji of Upward and Download arrow in Line Notify by PHP

Tags: php, line

I am developing the PHP code to send a message with the Upward and Downward emoji, representing the high price and low price respectively. However, I do not the emoji ID of the emoji. So could you please tell me how I can find these?

I tries to look at this link, but not found.
https://developers.line.me/media/messaging-api/emoji-list.pdf

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you understand how to use the unicode to send the emoji but don't know the required codes. Therefore, if you know what you are looking for, you can easily get the codes from https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html

Comment: @Ponomy In that case close the question and mark it as answer